# jQuery select all A's except one specific

Tags: jquery, filter, selector, href

I need help with jQuery, currently I am using the following selector.

```
$("#myDiv>a")
```

Which will select all 50 links in my division, how do I filter out a specific link from being selected? My link href contains "cat -kennel" and I tried using a(href*-cat-kennel) but it does not work??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:not` selector.

```
$('#myDiv a:not([href*="cat-kennel"])');
```

If your filter logic is more complex, you can use `filter`.

```
$('#myDiv a').filter(function (index) {
    //return true/false based on specific logic
    //'this' points to the element
});
```

Comment: Thank you, however in my environment your code fails to work. The use of the 'not' filter, is there any other way around this??

Comment: @LeeCook Could you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows how you tried the implementation? Also have you tried with `filter`?